# Find Document by GUID 

Tags: development, spweb, spfile, guid

I'm missing something that must be so simple that it's not even worth asking... but I have an object ID (GUID)... How do I figure out the document it points to?

For example I have a GUID of `137DA01F-9AFD-5d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8` and need to know what file/url it points to.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you know the SPWeb but not the document library, you can use [`SPWeb.GetFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473996.aspx):

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile(guid);
```

Comment: +1 Best solution! Haven't seen this method yet. Just tested: it works perfectly. Interesting thing: SPListItem.UniqueId and SPListItem.File.UniqueId are the same guids.

Comment: @omlin - Thanks! `GetFile` and `GetFolder` They also have overloads with URLs, which can be very useful - it lets you access files ad folders without getting the library first.

Comment: Yep, actually I knew about these methods, but only about Url overloads :) And even if I have seen GUID overloads, how could one suppose, that `listItem.UniqueId` can be equal to `listItem.File.UniqueId`?! Very uncommon usage for property with such name, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 10):

**Simpliest case**

Consider you know that document is stored in standard "Shared Documents" library from the Team Site Template, you should use this code:

```
var library = web.GetListFromUrl("http://site/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx");
var file = library.Items[new Guid("137DA01F-9AFD-5d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8")].File;
// file.Url - site-relative url of the file
// file.OpenBinary() - get file contents (returns byte[])
```

MSDN references:

1. [SPListItemCollection.Item(Guid)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460911.aspx)
2. [SPFile.OpenBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477413.aspx) (with sample code)

**Library with folders**

In more complex case, when you have some folders in your document library, probably the best way will be to use the CAML query for this purpose:

```
var query = new SPQuery();
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
query.View = 
@"<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name=\"UniqueId\">
    <Value Type='Text'>137DA01F-9AFD-5d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>";
var items = library.GetItems(query);
```

**Library unknown**

If you even don't know in which library the file is stored, you should go through all the libraries of the site:

```
 foreach (var library in web.Lists)
 {
     if (!library.Hidden && library is SPDocumentLibrary)
     {
         // ... try to get the file and so on
     }
 }
```

**Document IDs**

Also, you should surely read about Document IDs feature, which allows you to reference a document from anywhere:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/blairb/archive/2009/10/20/new-document-id-feature-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Note: Your Guid, of course, is not a document ID.

Answer (score 6):

There's the [SPList.GetItemByUniqueId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyuniqueid.aspx) function, but if you don't know which list to search you're out of luck.

If you're using SharePoint 2010, look at the Document ID functionality (which attaches a unique ID to a list item and then uses Search to find the item). Depending upon your requirements, you might consider implementing "FindItemInSiteCollectionByUniqueId" using a similar approach to Document IDs, making the guid a Managed Property and conducting a search via code.