# Same GUID'S for files in sharepoint 2013 library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, guid

I have come across one rare incident while i'm doing some work with SharePoint 2013 library and the issue is i'm getting same GUID's for 3 files while retrieving files information from the library.
Can anyone explain is this possible in Sharepoint ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of links which might prove useful for you.  This blog post  describes the same issue you have, it sounds a bit worrying - read the part under the heading 'Predicament': [finding duplicate GUIDs](https://sharepointinterface.com/2011/04/03/finding-duplicate-guids-in-your-sharepoint-site-collection/),

The other link is to our beloved SP Stack Exchange [Find document by GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12038/find-document-by-guid) - I think this is useful for some background knowledge on GUIDs, there are additional links given in some of the answers.

Good luck